# Tellement/aussi

Tags: choix-de-mot

I'm wondering if the sentence below is correct or if **tellement** needs to be substituted with "aussi"?

Il habite avec Fleur depuis presque un an maintenant, et en fait c’est la première fois qu’il est avec une fille **tellement** longtemps

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct. "Aussi" is "as" (comparisons) and "so" (otherwise). "Tellement" is  basically "so".

- Il habite avec Fleur depuis presque un an maintenant, et en fait c’est la première fois qu’il est avec une fille aussi longtemps.

It is not the most idiomatic way of saying what is intended, although the  use of the verb "habiter" first leaves no doubt as to what "être" means in "qu'il est avec"; the verbs "vivre" or "habiter" are more usual. "Être" is too general: it means also and often simply to be talking with a girl or more often to be engaged with her at a given moment in whichever of the usual activities that lovers like (in particular sex).

- Il habite avec Fleur depuis presque un an maintenant, et en fait c’est la première fois qu’il vit/habite avec une fille aussi longtemps.

Comment: You are indeed correct in stating that the version "with "tellement" is not correct and "tellement" needs to be substituted by "aussi". However, your comparison with English language is misleading: I am pretty sure that in English it would be said "it is the first time he is with a girl for so long", not "as long". So your translations are correct in general, but not in this particular case where "so" will be translated into "aussi"...

Comment: @Steph I see, right, I take into account only the comparisons.